# Gnome-Terminal Unmet Dependencies issue on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, gnome-terminal

I tried to run `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal` in PangoTerm.

Then I got this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed.
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies: gnome-terminal :
Depends: libvte-2.91-0 (>= 0.60.2) but 0.60.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
Recommends: nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

When I try to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` the output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done 
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
apg avahi-utils cups-pk-helper firmware-manager-notify firmware-manager-shared
gnome-control-center-faces gnome-online-accounts gnome-terminal-data ippusbxd
libcolord-gtk1 libfirmware-manager libgsound0 libpop-upgrade-gtk librygel-core-2.6-2
librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2
libs76-hidpi-widget mobile-broadband-provider-info mousetweaks
network-manager-gnome pop-upgrade pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-macaroonbakery python3-protobuf
python3-pymacaroons python3-rfc3339 rygel system-config-printer system-config-printer-common
system-config-printer-udev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: The package I picked from one of your messages is what is available (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libvte) so either you've software lists are out-of-date & need updating (`sudo apt update` and any errors listed need fixing), your chosen mirror is out-of-date (check from output with `sudo apt update` & mirror list https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors OR what it said, you have held broken packages from prior commands (*which need to be fixed first*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Please also add the output of `sudo apt autoremove` (after making sure you run `sudo apt update` prior to every `apt` session)

Comment: Thanks Sir @Nmath , this is First time i asking in here

Comment: @guiverc unfortunately no, it still outputing ask to removing a lot package, should i do `sudo apt autoremove` ?

Comment: @guiverc I Solved with installing `libvte-2.91-0` and`libvte-2.91-common` manually, thanks for the references :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing libvte-2.91-0 and libvte-2.91-common packages manually.

1. [Fix broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081938/)
2. Run the following commands.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common
   ```

Comment: thanks bro, i use this method and its works perfectly :)